# why Kafka delete my data replicated by mirrormaker2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

It's strange that after i start mm2 to replicate date from source cluster A to target cluster B,
While data is being copied, it is also being deleted。see the pictures：

[image]

[image]

It eventually delete all the data that was copied in cluster B.
I can't figure out why this happend, does any one can help me?

Comment: even though i stop mirrormaker， all data will be deleted eventually too.

Comment: Yes, Kafka itself "eventually deletes" data, which has nothing to do with MirrorMaker. What are your retention settings on the topic?

Comment: you are right.the source cluster set topics retention.ms for 1 year, but mm2 didn't replicate that , in the target cluster, retention.ms is 7 days。

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the source cluster set topics retention.ms for 1 year, but mm2 didn't replicate that , in the target cluster, retention.ms is 7 days。

so it's a config problem.